# Is it possible to view the contents of an underlying NFS mount without unmounting the NFS content?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, mount

I have a shared directory on a server - let's call it /home/shared - which is mounted with content from another server via nfs.

When it is unmounted /home/shared is *supposed* to be empty - however, running **du -x** on the directory indicates that it is not empty.

I cannot unmount the NFS content to inspect the mount point, since it is in use by others.

**Is there any way that I can view/edit the contents of the actual mount point (not the NFS content) while leaving the NFS content mounted for others to use?**

Answer (score 8):

It might be easier to:

```
$ sudo mount --bind /directory_above_the_mount_point /some_temporary_directory
```

then, the `/directory_above_the_mount_point/mount_point` remains to show the mounted filesystem and at the same moment you can access the underlying filesystem (mount point) at `/some_temporary_directory/mount_point`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get a handle into the underlying directory, you could use `mount --move` to move the share out of the way, cd into the mountpoint, then use `mount --move` to move it back into place. Shouldn't disrupt anything.

A better option if you just want to view would be to use debugfs (or other equivalent) against the filesystem device itself to check that directory:

```
challenger:/home/michael # mount
/dev/mapper/system-opensuse on / type ext3 (rw,noatime)
/dev/mapper/system-home on /home type xfs (rw,noatime)
challenger:/home/michael # debugfs /dev/system/opensuse 
debugfs 1.41.9 (22-Aug-2009)
debugfs:  ls /home
 11751  (12) .    2  (4084) ..
debugfs:  quit
```

Answer (score 3):

You can **move** a mount in Linux using `mount --move`.  So if you're OK with a *very short* window of possible non-accessibility, you could do this:

1. Make a new temporary directory: `mkdir /home/shared-tmp`
2. Do the move: `mount --move /home/shared /home/shared-tmp && mv /home/shared /home/shared-old && mkdir /home/shared && mount --move /home/shared-tmp /home/shared`
3. Remove the temporary directory: `rmdir /home/shared-tmp`

This should leave `/home/shared` as the mounted directory, `/home/shared-old` as the old (suspected non-empty) directory.

Comment: As that would prevent other users from accessing the NFS data where they expect to find it, this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

you can mount the device on which your original files reside to another directory then drill down into to get to the contents of the directory.